# Card.io build error in local.properties

Tags: card.io

I have a problem built Card.Io source version with android studio.

like this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':card.io:cleanNative'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build''
```

and my local.properties file:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk
ndk.dir=C\:\\android-ndk-r10e
```

I think it right path, but the message said "error".

Please help me.

[this is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlzro.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `cleanNative` and `buildNative` use forward slashes for directory paths, which isn't compatible with Windows. I recommend fixing those, and trying again.  If you provide a fix that works for both Windows and *nix via a Pull Request, we'll happy review and accept.

Comment: I did using "/" so that is buildnative function :: task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:/temp/card.io-Android-source-master/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build",'-C',file('C:/temp/card.io-Android-source-master/card.io/src/main/jni').absolutePath,'-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),'all'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    } ,  ::::::::::::::::: it's error as well ....

Comment: Windows isn't going to understand that path.  You need windows safe paths.

Answer (score 0):

on windows system：

```
commandLine 'xxx'
```

should be changed into

```
commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'xxx'
```